# How to add a column containing sequential counts based on the order of another column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe like below:

```
data = [["Item_1", '2020-06-01'], ["Item_1", "2021-05-01"], ["Item_1", '2019-02-10'],
       ["Item_2", '2020-04-01'], ["Item_2", "2018-05-01"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Item_ID", "Dates"])
```

```
Item ID   Dates
Item_1    2020-06-01
Item_1    2020-05-01
Item_1    2019-02-10
Item_2    2020-04-01
Item_2    2018-05-01
```

I am hoping to add a column that contains a count based on the date order. So that table would look like below, where the `Dates` column is re-ordered and the count column reflects the order with which the `Item ID` is dated:

```
Item ID   Dates       Count
Item_1    2019-02-10    1
Item_1    2020-05-01    2
Item_1    2020-06-01    3
Item_2    2016-02-10    1
Item_2    2018-05-01    2
```

Is there a way to do this that doesn't rely on a `groupby` operation such that the original dataframe is updated with this new column?

Comment: 1. What do you have against groupby? 2. What is `count` supposed to represent?

Comment: I suppose I am not against groupby, I was more hoping to add this column to the original dataframe but I actually think for what I intend, groupby would be fine. And `count` represents the order - so 1 means it's the first date associated with the item and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
df = df.sort_values(['Item ID','Dates'])
df['int'] = df.groupby('Item ID').cumcount()+1
```